# wxPython and win32gui matching size/position of open window not accurate

Tags: wxpython, win32gui

I'm trying to use wxPython to create windows (or a frame) that is the exact position and size of a different open window on my desktop. The code seems to be working, but the size and/or position is slightly off and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code for checking what windows are open (using win32ui) and creating the wx.Frame:

```
class WxFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, style):
        super().__init__(None, title='Viewer', style=style)
        panel = WxPanel(self)

class WxPanel(wx.Panel): 

    def __init__(self, parent): 
        super().__init__(parent)


# callback for determining open windows, locations, and sizes

def callback(hwnd, win_list):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        window_title = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)

        rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
        x = rect[0]
        y = rect[1]
        w = rect[2] - x
        h = rect[3] - y

        name = window_title
        location = (x, y)
        size = (w, h)

        if window_title:
            win_list["window_name"].append(name)
            win_list["window_location"].append(location)
            win_list["window_size"].append(size)

    return True

# create a dictionary with info about each open window
win_list = {
    "window_name": [],
    "window_location": [],
    "window_size": []
}
win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, win_list)  

app = wx.App()

# loop through each open window, checking if the name is an open calculator 
window
for i in range(len(win_list["window_name"])):    
    if win_list["window_name"][i] == "Calculator":        
        position = win_list["window_location"][i]
        size = win_list["window_size"][i]

        frame = WxFrame(None, style=wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.BORDER_NONE )
        frame.SetPosition( position )
        frame.SetSize(wx.Size(size[0], size[1]))
        frame.SetBackgroundColour('BLUE')
        frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

When I run this code, the frame is created and it is very CLOSE to the size of the calculator on my desktop, but not quite, as you can see in the following image:

[Calculator on top of Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zloYG.png)

[image]

As you can see, when I click the calculator in taskbar after running the program to show the calculator on top of the frame, the blue frame is visible around the edges of the calculator, so the size of the frame is not correct because it doesnt match exactly the size of the calculator. What am I doing wrong? I tried running program without wx.NO_BORDER style, but then its the exact same problem with a border around the frame instead of no border.

thanks for your help